# EXTJS OnClick Tab Event

Tags: extjs, tabs

Is there a way to attach an OnClick event to a tab switch in EXTJS?

I make the grid like this:

> ```
> var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({
>     labelWidth: '100%',
>     border:false,
>     width: '100%',
>             style: 
>             {
>                 height: '291px'
>             },
>     items: {
>         xtype: 'tabpanel',
>         activeTab: 0,
>         //labelWidth: 75, // label settings here cascade unless overridden
>         items:[{
>         url:'save-form.php',
>         title: 'Tab 1',
>   ...
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added in a listener after the tabs were defined like this:

```
//define all tabs, and after the ] from the tab panel JSON: 
listeners: {
    'tabchange': function(tabPanel, tab) {
        alert("tab changed");
    }
}
```

This just alerts when the tab changed, which is sufficient for my purposes. I'm not sure though how to find out which tab is the current tab.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: `Ext.TabPanel.getActiveTab()` returns component being the active tab.

Comment: The second parameter in your tabchange eventhandler will be a reference to the activated tab.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `tabchange` event that fires when the active tab changes: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_FAQ_TabPanel

Answer (score 1):

```
There is no event for tab click in TabPanel, however you can bind into click event on each tab. You can add custom event. 
Following example help to you. 


{
  xtype : 'tabpanel',
  items : [{
    xtype : 'panel', 
    title:  'ABC'
   },{
      xtype : 'panel',
      title : 'XYZ'
}],
  listeners: {
    render: function() {
     this.items.each(function(panel){
         // Added tabclick event for tabpanel                                                                        
         panel.tab.on('click', function(){
       panel.addEvents('tabclick');  // addded event to panel 
       panel.fireEvent('tabclick', panel);
      });
       });
      }
    }
        }
```